# Training TF object detection to detect 300 instances on the same image

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've been trying to train an object detection pipeline on top of the `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous` to recognize a single class, but many times on the same image. My goal is to able to count how many instances are on each image, rather than knowing exactly what and where is something on the image.

The training dataset are 20 images with around 300 boxes on each, and so are the evaluation images.

I can't get the pipeline to detect more than 20 instances on each image, even on the original training ones, no matters how small the loss gets after 200k training steps.

I've configured the pipeline with 
`first_stage_max_proposals: 2000`
and 
`max_detections_per_class: 500`
`max_total_detections: 500`

But nothing seems to change the limit of 20ish detected boxes; nor adding more training steps.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: the evaluation tool has its own setting of how many max boxes to print on each sample image; which defaults to 20. When I asked the question it wasn't even available in the settings, but lost in the evaluation code. Now it is available as `eval_config.max_num_boxes_to_visualize`

Answer (score 0):

Are these objects very close to each other? The object detection API uses nms to suppress boxes that overlap more than a certain threshold

Comment: I’ve set nms threshold to 0 and iou to 0.95 with same results. Any suggestions ?